# How can I run a command line only program when I insert an audio CD?

Tags: sound, cd

The Removable Media settings in Ubuntu don´t list command line only programs.

I´d like to run the command line tool *abcde* when I insert an audio CD.

How do I get Ubuntu´s settings to recognise *abcde* as an option?

I`m on Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

The program [udevautorun](http://linlog.skepticats.com/content/udevautorun/) allows you to do this.
Install `udev` from either their site or by running

```
sudo apt-install udev
```

Once installed, navigate to `/etc/dev.d/block` and put [usbdrive.dev](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TnBZzq6mv8/) into that folder.

Then once that is done, write whichever script you want to run when the disc is inserted, place it in `/etc/udev`, and specify the block device you want to trigger the script.